# Android - How to activate calling Emergency numbers using Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application in which there is an Emergency numbers calling functionality. I am using the call code below:

```
private void call(String pnum) {
    private TelephonyManager telephone;
    private PhoneListener phList;
    telephone = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    phList = new PhoneListener(this);
    telephone.listen(phList, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + pnum));
    call.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(call);
    finish();
}
```

and the `PhoneListener` class is as below:

```
public class PhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {
   boolean called = false;
   TelephonyManager mTelMgr;
   InitiateScreen m;

   public PhoneListener(InitiateScreen activity) {
       mTelMgr = (TelephonyManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       m = activity;
    }

   @Override
   public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String inNum) {
       super.onCallStateChanged(state, inNum);

       // Don't fire before the call was made
       if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
        called = true;

       // Call has ended -- now bring the activity back to front
       if (called && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
        called = false;
        mTelMgr.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
       }
    }
   }
```

As i am using `INTENT.ACTION_CALL`, the call should be automatically happened. But for Emergency numbers Dial Pad showing(`ACTION_DIAL`). I have verified the same code with non-emergency numbers. Call is automatically going. So, Doesn't Android supports calling the Emergency numbers directly. Can't we invoke `ACTION.CALL` for Emergency numbers in Android. Please help me with your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this in your activity

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "911"));
startActivity(intent);`

Add this permission to your manifest:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: Do u understand the code what i have placed above? I am particularly asking about Emergency Numbers.

Comment: @Mex He is asking about Emergency call not for any specific telephone number.....Hope you understand..!!

Comment: Ou sorry... should the App work all over the world ? Maybe its a possibility to locate the phone and get the Country with geocode... and then you take the number for this coutry                                 http://www.sccfd.org/travel.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void phoneCall()
{


   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+txtPhn.getText().toString().trim()));
   callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 


   startActivity(callIntent);



}
```